# Unable to display correct coordinates of a selected marker

Tags: leaflet, marker, coordinate

I built a map with Leaflet (inside a Qlikview extension) with many markers.
I want my users go to the map and when they double click on a marker, it displays coordinates.
With the following code, when I click on a marker, I have always coordinates of last marker fetched, not the selected one.
I want to put coordinates in latSel e lonSel variables.

```
for (var i=0,k=_this.Data.Rows.length;i<k;i++){
       var row = _this.Data.Rows [i];

       var latitude = parseFloat(row[0].text.replace(",","."));
       var longitude = parseFloat(row[1].text.replace(",","."));

       //Check to see coordinates are valid
        if (latitude != NaN && latitude !='' && latitude <= 90 && latitude >= -90 && longitude != NaN && longitude !='' && longitude <= 180 && latitude >= -180) {

         var latlng = new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
         var poptext = 'Lat & Long:'+latlng+'<br/>'+ row[2].text +'<br/>'+ 'Measure: ' + row[4].text;
         var marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup(poptext);

         marker.on('dblclick', function(e){
                                        latSel = marker.getLatLng().lat;
                                        lonSel = marker.getLatLng().lng
                                        //_this.Data.SelectTextsInColumn(0, true, latSel);
                                        alert("latitude = " + latSel);

                                    });

        } else {
         //
           }    
     }
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `onClick` listeners in loops can be a bit tricky (search for "javascript onclick loop" in your favourite search engine and you will find some solutions).

Instead of using the `marker` variable, in Leaflet you can use the variable `this` inside the callback which refers back to the marker, like so:

```
marker.on('dblclick', function(e){
    latSel = this.getLatLng().lat;
    lonSel = this.getLatLng().lng;
    alert(latSel);
});
```

See demo code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RU3SsoI6A16AYOQAq0xV?p=preview